# Atoms in a countable space

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Let  $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ be a measurable space where $\Omega$ is countable.

I am trying to prove that there is some partition $\mathcal{P}$ of $\Omega$ such that the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ is the set of all possible unions of sets in $\mathcal{P}$.

I think this partition should be the one given by atoms:

$$ \mathcal{P} = \{P_x:x\in \Omega \}$$ where $$P_x=\bigcap_{F\in\mathcal{F} : x\in F} F$$

I could show that this is a partition, and that  $\mathcal{F}\subseteq U(\mathcal{P})$ where by $U(\mathcal{P})$ I indicate the set of all possible unions of sets in $\mathcal{P}$.

To finish, I need to prove that $P_x \in \mathcal{F}$.
I know this is not true in general, but maybe there is an easy proof in the case $\Omega$ is countable?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $y\notin P_x$, there exists some $F_y\in \mathcal F$ such that $x\in F_y$ and $y\notin F_y$. Then the countable(!) union
$$ \bigcup_{y\in \Omega\setminus P_x}F_y$$
is in $\mathcal F$ and its complement is just $P_x$.

Comment: This doesn't quite work - if you replace each $F_y$ in the union with its complement then we're in business (since the complement necessarily has empty intersection with $P_x$ and the union obviously contains all $y\notin P_x$). Or you could instead replace the union with an intersection and get $P_x$ directly.